# Is there a documentation about "Config_heavy.pl" keys?

Tags: perl, cpan, cc

After installing perl you can find a `Config_heavy.pl` file e.g. in `/usr/lib/perl5/5.18/mach/Config_heavy.pl` and I wonder if there is a commentation of all key/value pairs one can find in it. The of them are clear, but sometimes I'm not sure.

Calling `perl -V` shows all these values in there.

I guess what I really want to know is, which values are really 'hard', because not only in this file so a change would have no effect, an which have an effect after change? E.g. which can I change to have an effect in CPAN like adding a '`-I.`' to the ccflags to have CPAN searching for local headers included with <> instead of "" (you can find this in Authen::PAM ;) ).

So if there is some more information do find about the keys in this file, I would be happy to learn about them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the command line,

```
perldoc Config
```

You shouldn't change that file.

---

I think the following will do the trick to install Authen::PAM:

```
wget http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/N/NI/NIKIP/Authen-PAM-0.16.tar.gz
tar xvzf Authen-PAM-0.16.tar.gz
cd Authen-PAM-0.16
perl Makefile.PL CCFLAGS='-I.'
make test
make install
```